# Cut n cells and insert to below row using excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying cut 4 adjacent cells and insert a new row below and paste it on a new row.
My input is similar to
[image]
 I have 4 columns Addr,Phone,Count,Amount. Some Rows of my excel sheet contains multiple n numbers of entries. I want to cut multiple of 4 cells and insert a new row below and paste it on.
The output would be similar to 
[image]
I tried with transform function but unable to produce the expected result. 
How can I do this with vba code or any excel functions

Comment: please share the what ever code you are wrote for above issue

Comment: As this is not a free coding service, please post your code and I'll be happy to help.

Comment: Why don't you copy column A values down with the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code its exactly work with your requirement

```
Sub Narasappa()
For i = 2 To 1000


       If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(5).Cells(i, 2) = "" Then 
       Exit For
       End If

        For j = 6 To 1000 Step 4

            If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(5).Cells(i, j).Value = "" Then
                Exit For
                Else
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(5).Cells(i, j).Resize(, 4).Cut
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(5).Range("B" & i + 1).Insert xlShiftDown
                End If

                Next

           Next

End Sub
```

Comment: @Narasappa  Change the sheet name as you wish